# fopen works fwrite doesn't? don't think it is permissions

Tags: php, permissions, fwrite

here's my code:

```
<?php
$getfromdb = 5;
$filename = 'file'.$getfromdb.'.php';
fopen($filename, 'w');
fwrite($filename, '<?php echo "works!"; ?>');
fclose($filename);
?>
```

I've changed all of the files in the directory to 777 permissions. the file 'file5.php' is created, but has 664 permissions, so I set it to 777 permissions. when I then run the program it gives me the errors:

Warning: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /srv/disk4/865173/www/fishtaco.mypressonline.com/sitequinetest.php on line 5

and the same for fclose on line 6... even though 'file5.php' has 777 permissions.

im using 'awardspace.com' as my host,

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You need a file handle, not a filename: `$fp = fopen($filename, 'w'); fwrite($fp, ...);`

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a stream ressource with fopen and then pass it to fwrite:

```
<?php
$getfromdb = 5;
$filename = 'file'.$getfromdb.'.php';
$ressource = fopen($filename, 'w');
fwrite($ressource, '<?php echo "works!"; ?>');
fclose($ressource);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to write to a filename instead of the file handle returned by `fopen`. Try this code:

```
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
if($fp) {
    fwrite($fp, '<?php echo "works!"; ?>');
    fclose($fp);
}
```